# How to apply `org-mode` to files called `TODO` and also ending with `.org`

Tags: org-mode

I want to apply `org-mode` by default into files called `TODO` and also ones that are ending with `.org`.

I have done following but neither worked. What might preventing to set `org-mode` by default?

```
(require 'org)
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)

(setq org-log-done t)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (local-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'org-show-subtree)))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("TODO\\'" . org-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))

(defvar no-flyspell-list '("TODO"))
```

Comment: Did you restart emacs? Assuming that the above is in your init file, it should then work.

Comment: Actually I did multiple times and reboot the computer as well but it did not help :-(

Comment: Do `C-h v auto-mode-alist RET` and look for the two entries above. Doing the two `add-to-list` calls above was enough for my emacs to open `TODO` and `something.org` files in Org mode.

Comment: Please see line 5 and 82 (output of my `auto-mode-alist`) I can see the set `.org-mode` (https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/4bc474a7abdc91a15e481f22fca1be81) but it does not have any effect :-(

Comment: Do all the other entries work? I can't see any reason for this not to be working, but maybe I'm being blind and somebody will point out the problem.

Comment: I don't use all entries, but the ones I am using works fine such as: the ones for `markdown-mode`, `python-mode`, and `latex-mode`

Comment: I have ` -*- outline -*-` at the beginning of the buffer, when I removed it seems like it start working

Comment: Phew - you had me going there. Is there an asterisk between the two dashes, I hope? Like this: `-*- outline -*-`. That's what [emacs looks for at the beginning of the file for file-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

Comment: Yes sir it was like `-*- outline -*-` , I took it from an example todo file and had no idea would have an affect like this. // on the other hand `*outline*` works.